# Glide gradle not recognizing ModelLoader

Tags: java, android-glide, firebaseui

I'm trying to use **FirebaseUI** to retrieve a photo from **Firebase Storage** and show it directly in my imageview using **Glide**.
In order to do that I've created a **ModelLoader** as shown in Firebase Documentation:

```
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.Registry;
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule;
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule;
import com.firebase.ui.storage.images.FirebaseImageLoader;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

import java.io.InputStream;

@GlideModule
public class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {
    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide, Registry registry) {
        // Register FirebaseImageLoader to handle StorageReference
        registry.append(StorageReference.class, InputStream.class,
                new FirebaseImageLoader.Factory());
    }
}
```

This file is inside my project folder so gradle should recognize it.
The problem is, everytime I run the app and this line of code executes:
`Glide.with(context!!).load(reference).into(binding.imgPhoto)` this error appears:

```
W/Glide: Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored
E/GlideExecutor: Request threw uncaught throwable
    com.bumptech.glide.Registry$NoModelLoaderAvailableException: Failed to find any ModelLoaders registered for model class: class com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.ModelLoaderRegistry.getModelLoaders(ModelLoaderRegistry.java:77)
        at com.bumptech.glide.Registry.getModelLoaders(Registry.java:585)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeHelper.getLoadData(DecodeHelper.java:207)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeHelper.getCacheKeys(DecodeHelper.java:224)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.ResourceCacheGenerator.startNext(ResourceCacheGenerator.java:44)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:276)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:393)
```

What is happening? I've created the Loader, Invalidated Caches, Restarted, and the problem still isn't solved...

Comment: Any chance you solved this? @AndreNogueira?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to create a class (e.g MyAppGlideModule) that extends AppGlideModule and use GlideApp.with... instead of Glide.with... check this [link](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/storage/README.md) for full explanation

> The class MyAppGlideModule can live anywhere in your source directory and is processed by the Glide annotation processor at compile time in order to create the GlideApp class.

For kotlin:

```
@GlideModule
class AppGlide: AppGlideModule(){

    override fun registerComponents(
        context: android.content.Context,
        glide: Glide,
        registry: Registry
    ) {
        super.registerComponents(context, glide, registry)
        registry.append(
            StorageReference::class.java, InputStream::class.java,
            FirebaseImageLoader.Factory()
        )

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I really wish the developer documents mentioned this instead of just putting a single function without much additional info on https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files

Comment: Don't know why, but using Glide instead of GlideApp works for me.