# Failed to find any ModelLoaders registered for model class: class com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-glide

I've gone through all the previously asked questions on this topic. But the solutions mentioned aren't working out for me.

As prescribed in the Glide readme, I've registered a model loader for my app, it resides in the app->src->java directory:
`MyAppGlideModule.java`:

```
package com.kenadams.app;

import android.content.Context;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.Registry;
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule;
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule;
import com.firebase.ui.storage.images.FirebaseImageLoader;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

import java.io.InputStream;

@GlideModule
public class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide, Registry registry) {
        // Register FirebaseImageLoader to handle StorageReference
        registry.append(StorageReference.class, InputStream.class,
                new FirebaseImageLoader.Factory());
    }

}
```

This is how I'm calling the Glide module in my adapter class:
`adapter.java`

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(topicAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
  //Setting text      
holder.textView.setText(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(this.data.get(position),HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
//Setting image
        Glide.with(holder.iv.getContext()).load(sr.child("/1.png")).into(holder.iv);


    }
```

There are no syntax errors and the app is compiling successfully, yet I keep getting this runtime error:

```
com.bumptech.glide.Registry$NoModelLoaderAvailableException: Failed to find any ModelLoaders registered for model class: class com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.ModelLoaderRegistry.getModelLoaders(ModelLoaderRegistry.java:77)
        at com.bumptech.glide.Registry.getModelLoaders(Registry.java:594)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeHelper.getLoadData(DecodeHelper.java:212)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeHelper.getCacheKeys(DecodeHelper.java:229)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.ResourceCacheGenerator.startNext(ResourceCacheGenerator.java:47)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:311)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:277)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:235)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:413)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultPriorityThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:372)
```

Some answers have previously mentioned to use `GlideApp` instead of `Glide`.However, **this doesn't work for me.**
I keep getting the syntax error:
`Cannot resolve symbol 'GlideApp'`

Further when I try to build the module , the build keeps failing due `android-exported:true` not being in the `intent filter`. This doesn't make sense as `MyAppGlideModule` extends `AppGlideModule` and not `AppCompatActivity`. So, even if I wanted to add an intent filter with `android-exported:true` I'd be unable to do so.

Comment: This helped me finally figure this out. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60412648/glide-gradle-not-recognizing-modelloader)

Answer (score 4):

What dependencies are you using?

Make sure you have this is added for Kotlin:

```
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.14.2'
```

or this for Java:

```
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.14.2'
```

Your finished Glide code should look something like this:

```
Glide.with(this).load(FirebaseStorageUtil.pathToReference(user.profilePicturePath))
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_baseline_account_circle_24)
                    .into(binding.profilePictureImageView)
```

Comment: Here is the Kotlin Documentation for adding the Annotation Processor to the compiler (in Groovy and Kotlin):
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kapt.html#cd73883

Answer (score 1):

What dependencies are you using?

Make sure you have this added for Kotlin:

```
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.14.2'
```

or this for Java:

```
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.14.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

It actually works without the kapt, all you need is this from Firebase:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:7.2.0'
```

as noted in the [Firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files).

However, what tripped me, is that the example in the abovementioned doc doesn't download the file before calling Glide :) This code works well with just the Firebase dependency:

```
Firebase.storage(remoteBucket)
.reference
.child(remoteFullPath)
.downloadUrl   // <- Hello! it is me you're looking for
.addOnSuccessListener {
    try {
        Glide.with(this)
            .load(it)
            .into(imageView)
    } catch (ex: IllegalArgumentException) {
        Timber.e(ex.localizedMessage)
    }
}
```